# How do I integrate and plot the function $\int\int e^{-x\cdot y}dx dy$ numerically?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, numerics

I would like to integrate the function $e^{-x\cdot y}$ numerically (in the fictitious assumption that there would be no closed form for it).

As a result a plot should come out that looks as follows:

[image]

A certain loss of precision is ok. I tried to use `F[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-x*y], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]` and `Plot3D[F[p, q], {p, -0.5, 0.5}, {q, -0.5, 0.5}]` but could not succeed. For any help I would be very grateful.

Comment: `F[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-x*y], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]` uses `x` and `y` as both function arguments and variables of integration, which generates an error message, as it should..

Comment: You can't integrate w.r.t. to a number !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need integration variables that differ from the parameters of `F`, and
2. you need definite integration limits.

This works:

```
F[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-x1*y1], {x1, -∞, x}, {y1, -∞, y}]

Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -0.4, 0.4}, {y, -0.4, 0.4}]
```

[image]

The numerical integral only works for $x<0$ and $y<0$, just like the analytic one too:

```
Assuming[Element[x | y, Reals], 
  Integrate[Exp[-x1*y1], {x1, -∞, x}, {y1, -∞, y}]]

(*    -ExpIntegralEi[-x*y] if x<0 && y<0    *)
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, which is very helpful. Does it mean, we have no chance to get the desired plot in an established (well-defined) manner, but only this quarter? Four separate charts would be fine for me too.

Comment: I get much faster result by first integrating it analytically once, then use the plot3D command.   Something like `F = Integrate[  Exp[-x1*y1], {x1, -Infinity, x}, {y1, -Infinity, y},   GenerateConditions -> False];
Plot3D[F, {x, -0.4, 0.4}, {y, -0.4, 0.4}]`  But this does not give exactly the plot given in OP.  Using `Abs@F` or `Re@F` gets closer but still not the same plot. Only half of it, it seems. Actually when used your code, I waited 3 minutes or so with no result. So I stopped it. I am using V 13.  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeZzS.png)

Comment: Good point. A special tricky thing here is to assume that no closed form exist. In such a case Mathematica would not yield a result by using `Integrate[]` - right? The function I am using as a reference is much simpler (for the sake of traceability and comprehensibility) as real world examples would be.

Comment: You can get the full plot with `Plot3D[F[-Abs[x], -Abs[y]], {x, -0.4, 0.4}, {y, -0.4, 0.4}]` but you may consider this cheating.